# Small caps for subsection-level headers in AMSART document class

Tags: sectioning, amsart

In the `amsart` class, subsection titles are in boldface. Is there a way to have them in `\textsc`?

Comment: @schtandard I cannot find the answer to this specific issue in that thread.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was going to recommend that you load the `sectsty` package and issue the directive `\subsectionfont{\normalfont\scshape}`, but then I remembered that the `sectsty` package is not compatible with the `amsart` document class. The `amsart` document class defines `\subsection` as follows:

```
\def\subsection{\@startsection{subsection}{2}%
  \z@{.5\linespacing\@plus.7\linespacing}{-.5em}%
  {\normalfont\bfseries}}
```

The directive `\@startsection` is a very-low-level LaTeX macro which takes six [6!] arguments. The final argument (default: `\normalfont\bfseries`) is relevant for the font shape and other characteristics used for the text of subsection-level headers.

To achieve your desired formatting objective, it suffices to add the following instructions to the preamble of your document:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox} % for "\patchcmd" macro
\patchcmd{\subsection}{\bfseries}{\scshape}{}{}
```

Do note that the second line in the preceding code blocks contains `\scshape` rather than `\textsc`. The former is a switch (just like `\bfseries`) which does *not* take an argument, whereas the latter is a command that takes an argument. Note that the original definition contains `\bfseries`, not `\textbf`, for the same reason: a switch is needed here.

---

A full MWE:

[image]

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\patchcmd{\subsection}{\bfseries}{\scshape}{}{}

\begin{document}
\setcounter{section}{1}
\subsection{Hello World}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This solutions seems to work perfectly. Thank you.